# How to run ContestAppletProd.jnlp?

Tags: java

I am trying to access topcoder arena but facing a problem. I am following the procedure given in the following link - http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=help&d2=getStarted

Currently openjdk-7-jdk is installed on my computer. On running "ContestAppletProd.jnlp" file, a pop-up from Firefox is asking me to download the file again and again. Any solutions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `javaws` to launch the .jnlp file

e.g `javaws -Xignoreheaders -headless Downloads/ContestAppletProd.jnlp &`

You can install `javaws` using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
sudo apt-get install icedtea-netx
```

Comment: use javaws to launch the .jnlp file

e.g javaws -Xignoreheaders -headless Downloads/ContestAppletProd.jnlp &"

Answer (score 2):

I have seen a lot of people facing similar problem. Topcoder arena just do not launch and shows some java Exception. Here is the list of solution that might help you.

Before trying this, I would recommend you to check if you have latest version of java installed.

**Solution 1:**

Does not matter if you are using windows, Linux or Mac, goto Terminal/CMD and run command

> javaws -viewer

(without quotes). When you run this command you will be taken to java applet cache windows. Delete whatever application you see there and restart your arena.
In most of the cases you should be able to launch your arena.
If you are not able to launch your arena even now, try solution 2

**Solution 2:**

Sometimes, topcoder arena applet takes a lot of time to run that might cross javaws timeout value. Fortunately, javaws provides us with command line option to change the timeout value. 
Run this command to launch topcoder arena with increased timeout:

> javaws -J-Dcom.topcoder.net.httptunnel.client.connect.timeout=X http://www.topcoder.com/contest/arena/ContestAppletProd.jnlp

Hope it helps. :)

Deepak Gupta

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Java-7 oracle instead of Icedtea. I got this after two days of struggle.

[install java-7-oracle](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/icedtea-web/+bug/969520/comments/14)

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer*
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer*
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*java*
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Update `/usr/bin/javaws`

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/javaws /usr/bin/javaws.old
vi /usr/bin/javaws
```

Change 2 parameters like this:

```
JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
CP=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar
```

Have fun!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple reversible method which you can try and which worked for me, I am not ubuntu user but Linux Mint user.

1. Go to Synaptics package manager
2. Search for javaws
3. You'll get results for icedtea, install it

This works!